# Merge UIView.layer strokes for animation

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, stroke

Is it possible to merge the strokes of multiple `UIViews`? I'd like to create a loading animation of two round views merging together and separating again:

[image: loading animation of two circles merging and separating again]

Where would I start? I already tried to use a CALayer but the strokes always overlapped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is just occurring to me that you can use 5 `UIView`s instead of merging the two and removing the shared area. Hum?

Comment: Or, a single image view with `[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"loader-" duration:1.0f];` [doc site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed:duration:)

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but I'd like it to be customizable (colors, sizes, ...). Unfortunately that's not possible with images only.